# How to read multiple lines of text in to one scalar variable in Perl

Tags: perl

I think this should be fairy straightforward. I am trying to set the contents of a kml file as a scalar (called $kml). At the moment it only stored the first line of kml. How can I make it ignore line breaks and read in the whole file?

I currently have:

```
$kml = "Scotland_one_inch_1st.kml";

open INPUT, "$kml";
$content = <INPUT>;
close INPUT;
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alter the record input separator, [`$/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24/):

```
{
    local $/ = undef;
    open my $INPUT, $kml or die "Unable to open '$kml': $!";
    $content = <$INPUT>;
    close $INPUT or die $!;
}
```

or just use a `join`:

```
open my $INPUT, $kml or die "Unable to open '$kml': $!";
$content = join '', <$INPUT>;
close $INPUT or die $!;
```

Comment: I tried your first solution and it worked a charm. cheers

Answer (score 4):

Use File::Slurp module.

```
my $text = read_file( 'filename' ) ;
```

Comment: +1 This is the simplest and most maintainable way!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a switch or set the input record separator (`$/`) in your script such that perl will slurp whole files. For convenience with one liners you can use `-0` to set the `IRS` to (alomst?) anything.

See [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) which will tell you haw to slurp by playing with `-0` to set the input record separator.  Setting `-0` to  `777` (`-0777`) will make perl slurp whole files whole because there is no legal character with that value.

If you want to slurp a file in a script but don't want to set the `IRS` for the entire script then something like the following would work (from [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)):

```
    open my $fh, "<", "foo" or die $!;
    local $/; # enable localized slurp mode
    my $content = <$fh>;
    close $fh;
```

The [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) docs explain why it's good to `local`ise the change to `$/`.

Comment: With the method described her you don't have to install ```File::Slurp``` ... so **+1** for me right **;-)**  However ```File::Slurp``` is pretty small and using its subroutines explicitly would allow you to handle the scope for the file reading methods your application might use in other places.